# "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<C3S.Models.Permission>' to 'bool'."

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm trying to code a Home screen so that a given user sees Menu Options depending on their Permissions.  Basically, going through each Menu Option, seeing what permissions are need to see it, and then checking to see if the current user has any of those permissions.

I'm trying with these lines of code in the Home Action

```
var userPermissionList = currentUser.Permissions;
List<MenuOption> optionList = context.MenuOptions.Where(mo => mo.Permissions.Intersect(userPermissionList, new PermissionComparer()));
```

and my implementation of the IEqualityComparer:

```
public bool Equals(Permission x, Permission y)
    {
        if (x.Id == y.Id && x.PermissionName.ToLower() == y.PermissionName.ToLower())
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        };
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Permission obj)
    {
        return obj.Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

However, at run time, I get these errors :

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to
>   'bool'.
>
> Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because
>   some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible
>   to the delegate return type.

What am I missing?

Comment: Your where clause is not saying what is supposed to be returned. It should be something like: `.Where(mo => mo.Permissions.Intersect(userPermissionList, new PermissionComparer()).Count() > 0);`

Comment: Or another logic that combines the MenuOptions to the user's Permissions. I don't know what is your intended logic between those two objects.

Comment: @RickWolff, your comment worked best for me.  Can you please move it to the answer section so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your where clause is not saying what is supposed to be returned. It should be something like:

```
.Where(
  mo => mo.Permissions.Intersect(userPermissionList, new PermissionComparer()).Count() > 0);
```

Or another logic that combines the MenuOptions to the user's Permissions. I don't know what is your intended logic between those two objects.

Answer (score 1):

```
mo.Permissions.Intersect(userPermissionList, new PermissionComparer())
```

is returning an IEnumerable but Where requires boolean logic.

Answer (score 1):

`Intersect` returns all matching items between two collections.  I think you just want `Contains`:

```
List<MenuOption> optionList = context.MenuOptions.Where(mo => userPermissionList.Contains(mo.Permissions, new PermissionComparer()));
```